# How do i get the elements form an Object array to a String array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I get a coding error in eclips Type mismatch, cannot convert Object to String. All data going into AL is String Type and AL is declared as String.
If i can just have AL go to a String[] that would be better.
heres my code:

```
Object[] Result;
AL.toArray (Result);
String[] news= new String[Result.length];
for (int i1=0;i1<news.length;i1++){
    news[i1]=Result[i1]; <=====here is where the error shows up
```

Comment: What's the data type of `AL`?

Comment: String is whats going into the AL

Comment: That's what goes in, but how is `AL` declared? Is it a `List<String>`, `List<Object>`, or something else?

Comment: Its declared as a String.

Comment: Um, how can `AL` be declared as a `String` when it has a `toArray` method?

Comment: AL is a ArrayList when I made it I declared it a String type

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
 news[i1]=Result[i1];
```

to this:

```
 news[i1]=Result[i1].toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try type casting.

```
news[i1] = (String) Result[i1];
```

However, it is probably a good idea to check the type of Result[i1] before type casting like that. So you could do something like

```
if( Result[i1] instanceof String){
 news[i1] = (String) Result[i1];
}
```

If you are absolutely sure that every object in Result array is String type, why don't you use String[] in the first place? Personally, I'm not a big fan of Object[]...

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(objectArray, objectArray.length, String[].class);
```

Comment: This will throw an `ArrayStoreException` unless all the elements of `objectArray` are already instances of `String`.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the `ArrayList.toArray()` method [with an existing array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) to define what type of array you want to get out of it.

So, you could do something like this:

```
String[] emptyArray = new String[0];
String[] news = AL.toArray(emptyArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Object[] Result = {"a1","a2","a3"};

    String[] AL = new String[Result.length];

    for(int a=0; a<Result.length; a++)
    {
        AL[a] = Result[a].toString();
    }

    System.out.println(AL[0]);
    System.out.println(AL[1]);
    System.out.println(AL[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `AL` is, as you report, an `ArrayList<String>`, this should do what you want in one line of code:

```
String[] news = AL.toArray(new String[AL.size()]);
```